# Can I use the output of an MCMC algorithm as the input of an independent Metropolis-Hastings algorithm?

Tags: sampling, markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, metropolis-hastings

Can I and if so, *how* can I, use the output of a MCMC method as the input for an independent Metropolis-Hastings algorithm? Maybe this question reduces to: How can I get (independent? or at least "almost uncorrelated") samples from a distribution which I only have access to through sampling from a Markov chain which has this distribution as its unique invariant distribution.

I've read about "thinning", but I'm not sure if it's appropriate. Especially since I have almost no knowledge about the target distribution and due to computational costs I don't want to perform pre-computation steps.

So, any suggestions?

*Remark*: To be clear: The problem is the following: Say my chain is $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ and suppose it was generated itself with a Metropolis-Hastings algorithm with a Gaussian proposal with a small variance. When I then would successively use $X_n,X_{n+1},\ldots$ for the proposal input of the other MCMC algorithm, those proposals would be highly correlated. In my case, I would actually want that successive proposals are "far apart" from each other.

Comment: Metropolis-within-Gibbs is an illustration of an MCMC method (MH) embedded into another MCMC method (Gibbs).

Comment: @Xi'an I've heard bout that. But is there also an MH inside MH?

Comment: The same principle applies, Gibbs being one special case of MH.

Comment: Do you have a good reference for Metropolis-within-Gibbs? Cannot find a good one on google.

Comment: There is a section about MwG in [our textbook](http://amzn.to/2lQDmJR). See also a [2006 paper by Roberts & Rosenthal.](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-16/issue-4/Harris-recurrence-of-Metropolis-within-Gibbs-and-trans-dimensional-Markov/10.1214/105051606000000510.pdf)

Comment: @Xi'an Could you briefly describe the principle? I've taken a look at both, your book and the paper, but it is still not clear to me how a "Metropolis-within-Metropolis" would look like.

Comment: @Xi'an The most natural thing, which would come to my mind, is simply using the transition kernel of one Metropolis-Hastings chain as the proposal kernel of another; but since that transition kernel does not have a density (I know that this is not really *necessary*; see [Tierney (1998)](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-8/issue-1/A-note-on-Metropolis-Hastings-kernels-for-general-state-spaces/10.1214/aoap/1027961031.full)), I guess that's not what you mean.